# When does a conic represent an empty set?

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

In my textbook of Arihant publications it says:

If a conic represents an empty set then, ∆ not= 0 and h^2

I don't understand what is meant by an empty set represented by the conic and how this relation is derived??

Comment: this seems incomplete.  What did you mean by "$\Delta \neq 0$ and $h^2$"? In any case, a conic can certainly be empty, as in $x^2+y^2=-1$.

Comment: For any conic- ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx +2fy +c =0.                                                                            ∆= abc+ 2fgh -af^2 - bg^2 - ch^2.                             ∆ regulates the nature of conic. If ∆= 0the equation represents pair of straight lines and if it is not it represents the conic section.